# When I click on Edit Source, the code is invisible, what next?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, edit

I am working on a two column layout.  When I click on edit source in the column I am working in, the code is invisible.  If I highlight over it, I obviously can see it.  Is there a setup that I have to active/disable in order to see the code again?

Comment: Hi @Krista Jovanovich, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 1):

You will follow below steps to see the Edit Source option for Content Editor Web Part.

1. Edit page.
2. Select your web part and click edit web part properties
3. Select your web part area. It will show the "FORMAT TEXT" tab under the ribbon bar.
4. Choose "Edit Source" option to see your code.

Let me know if I am understanding wrong.